# How to add students to class in by teacher in one click in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, m2m

I have models named Student and Teacher. Teacher will be able to see all the students through get api (students name). Now the requirement is, by just clicking one button on the side of the list of student name, teacher should be able to add the student to his class. How to associate students to teacher in this cases. Because same students can be added to other class by other teacher as well.

```
class Student(TimeStampAbstractModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

class Teacher(TimeStampAbstractModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="teacher", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question completely but a little bit.

If a `Teacher` can have multiple school-classes then you should add a third class:

```py
class SchoolClass(models.Model) # or TimeStampAbstractModel ?
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students_in_class = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

If a `Teacher` can only have one class then you can just add

```
students_in_class = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

to the Teacher Model.

I would recommend you to first add the one that fits the needs of your application and then go into Django Admin page and add a Teacher and some students and link them together and you'll get an understanding of how `ManyToManyFields` work.